# Azure runbook GetMember Error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I have the following runbook script which is supposed to copy application settings from one web app to another but when I run it I get an error.

```
# Get the credential to use for Authentication to Azure and Azure Subscription Name
$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'Credintial'
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred

$fromResourceGroup = 'parkprod'
$fromSite = 'parkprod'
$toResourceGroup = 'cmsfarhad'
$toSite = 'farhadparkingapi'

$props = (Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $fromResourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/Config -Name $fromSite/appsettings -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force).Properties

$hash = @{}
$props | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | % { $hash[$_.Name] = $props.($_.Name) }

Set-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $toResourceGroup -Name $toSite -AppSettings $hash
```

Error:

```
Environments                                                                                           Context          
------------                                                                                           -------          
{[AzureCloud, AzureCloud], [AzureChinaCloud, AzureChinaCloud], [AzureUSGovernment, AzureUSGovernment]} Microsoft.Azur...
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:10 char:11
+ $props = (Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $fromResour ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException

Get-Member : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not 
take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:13 char:10
+ $props | Get-Member -InputObject $f -MemberType NoteProperty | % { $h ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Member], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand

Get-Member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
At line:13 char:10
+ $props | Get-Member -InputObject $f -MemberType NoteProperty | % { $h ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand

Set-AzureRMWebApp : The term 'Set-AzureRMWebApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:15 char:1
+ Set-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $toResourceGroup -Name $toSite - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-AzureRMWebApp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [AzureRm.Websites](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Websites/1.0.4). A cmdlet from that module is missing. Check if you have installed it on your system, and if not install it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, as this is a runbook script, do I still need to install that cmdlet , or isn't it already included in there?

Answer (score 0):

As Peter says, the AzureRM.Websites PowerShell module does not currently ship in the Automation service and so you need to import this module yourself. Please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-resource-manager-support-azure-automation-runbooks/ for more details on that.

But it looks like you also have an issue with your use of the Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction cmdlet. The error being returned isn't very useful, and I'm not very familiar with that cmdlet, so hard for me to say what you're doing wrong. One thing to test would be to check if the same cmdlet call works from local PowerShell. If it does not work in local PowerShell, the issue is with your code and not any quirk in Azure Automation.